Why is the tetrahedron special?
I've wondered why the tetrahedron is special : It is the only Platonic Solid in 3 dimensions where faces are opposite to vertices; the other Platonic Solids have face-face and vertex-vertex opposite to each other.
That of course follows from the tetrahedron being its own dual,
but is there an algebraic explanation , maybe considering the symmetry group?
To rephrase, can we make the claim about a solid's dual and about its opposing faces from its symmetry group alone, or do we need more properties like the number of $k$-faces?

We may say that all other platonic solids have central symmetry (the symmetry group does tell us this much), so their opposite counterparts are themselves and not their own duals. This won't get us far, though. Say, a 2D square also has central symmetry (as do all even-sided regular 2D polygons), but despite that, is its own dual (as are all 2D regular polygons).

Also, of the 6 4d-d regular polytopes, only the hypertetrahedron and 24-cell have this property.  Both are self dual.

This is probably best understood as a property of all $n$-simplexes (simplices?).

@SidharthGhoshal how so?

We do not have much to go with , having just $5$ Platonic Solids.
Hence what-ever justification we make might be "tautological" , being not falsifiable.
Here are 2 ways to look at it , to justify why tetrahedron is special :
(A) Whether we have the ability to make the "opposite" vertex corner
Let the faces meeting at a vertex form a "corner" set of faces.
When we take away the corner , that is , the set of faces meeting at a vertex , then we must have enough material left over to make at least one more such vertex corner , where we might think that those vertex corner faces are symmetric hence the vertex-to-vertex , edge-to-edge , face-to-face orientation will occur.
In tetrahedron , with 4 faces where the corner has 3 faces meeting at a vertex , we have just $4-3=1$ face left over , which is not enough to make one more such vertex corner. Hence the vertex-to-vertex , edge-to-edge , face-to-face orientation will not occur.
In Cube , with 6 faces where the corner has 3 faces meeting at a vertex , we have $6-3=3=1 \times 3$ faces left over , which is enough to make one more such vertex corner. Hence the vertex-to-vertex , edge-to-edge , face-to-face orientation will occur.
In Octahedron , with 8 faces where the corner has 4 faces meeting at a vertex , we have $8-4=1 \times 4$ faces left over , which is enough to make one more such vertex corner. Hence the vertex-to-vertex , edge-to-edge , face-to-face orientation will occur.
In Dodecahedron , with 12 faces where the corner has 3 faces meeting at a vertex , we have $12-3=9=3 \times 3$ faces left over , which is enough to make $3$ more such vertex corners. Hence the vertex-to-vertex , edge-to-edge , face-to-face orientation will occur.
In Icosahendron , with 20 faces where where the corner has 5 faces meet at a vertex , we have $20-5=15=3 \times 5$ faces left over , which is enough to make $3$ more such vertex corners. Hence the vertex-to-vertex , edge-to-edge , face-to-face orientation will occur.
(B) Whether the total Symmetry group has the $\mathbb Z_2$ "factor"
The total Symmetry group for Cube + Octahedron is $\mathbb S_4 \times \mathbb Z_2$
The total Symmetry group for Dodecahedron + Icosahendron is $A_5 \times \mathbb Z_2$
Here we have the $\mathbb Z_2$ "factor" : Hence the vertex-to-vertex , edge-to-edge , face-to-face orientation will occur.
The total Symmetry group for tetradedron is $\mathbb S_4$
Here we do not have the $\mathbb Z_2$ "factor" : Hence the vertex-to-vertex , edge-to-edge , face-to-face orientation will not occur.
ADDENDUM :
Currently , this is intuition based on expectation.
Checking this in Higher Dimensions 4D , 5D might add support to that intuitive thinking.

Thanks, the $\mathbb{Z}_2$ factor is insightful. Does the 24-cell have a $\mathbb{Z}_2$ factor?

and is $\mathbb{Z}_2$ in these cases necessarily a direct factor? It seems more logical to me if it is a semidirect one.

I am still thinking about your 24-cell query , I am not able to conclude on it yet due to my $3D$ visualization limitations ! I might be able to report on certain interesting findings by tomorrow.
